# Dual Ethernet controller Ubuntu

Tags: ubuntu, wide-area-network

I just got a server and it has dual ethernet ports.  Is the purpose of that to have one inbound and one outbound?  I've done some quick googling and didn't see any straight up configurations for it.  How do I set this up?

I'm running a PHP/MySQL server and I'm wondering if I can utilize these dual ports to allow my server to handle more traffic or something....

Comment: See [bonding](http://serverfault.com/questions/tagged/bonding), [teaming](http://serverfault.com/questions/tagged/teaming), and [routing](http://serverfault.com/questions/tagged/routing).  There are lots of examples depending on you needs and what equipment you have.

Comment: "or something" sounds like you should profile the server for bottlenecks before messing with network configurations.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's **a lot** of different ways to configure two ethernet ports. Off the top of my head you can use them for redundancy, doubling the throughput, different networks, and plenty more.

What exactly do you want to do??

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to use both, you can only use one if you would prefer. If you aren't comfortable setting up bonding, I would just setup one and leave it be.